# Boxshadow inset can't recreate from Photoshop

Tags: html, css

So, here is what it needs to look like

[image]

You see that nice white effect on the center, I tried to recreate that, but with no succes here is my code:

```
  article .txt:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:50%;
    left:35%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a spread radius in your CSS declaration. That is, it should look something more like this (notice that in each of the box-shadow definitions there is a new "20px" number):

```
article .txt:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:50%;
    left:35%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

I also did a quick mockup in JSFiddle, you can see it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZEuZ6/

Answer (score 0):

From the image, it looks like what you want is not really a shadow, but a gradient.

Some good information on gradients: http://davidwalsh.name/css-gradients

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to reproduce is the white highlight on the device, try using a transparent PNG to achieve the effect, and absolutely position it over top of the image of the device.

An example would look like this

```
<figure class="frame">
    <img src="mobile-device.jpg" />
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
.frame { display: block; position: relative; }
.frame:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background: url('highlight.png');
    width: xx;
    height: yy;
    top: 0; left: 0;
 }
```